# Difference between passing 1024 and 2048 while generating Digital certificate

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

Little confused with below constructor code

With `2048`

```
 RSAKeyPairGenerator gen = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
 gen.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.valueOf(3),
                                new SecureRandom(), 2048, 80));
```

With `1024`

```
 RSAKeyPairGenerator gen = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
 gen.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.valueOf(3),
                                new SecureRandom(), 1024, 80));
```

Here is the [RSAKeyGenerationParameters](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/RSAKeyGenerationParameters.html), from [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library to generate certificates.

My question how what is the effect on public and private key by passing `1024` and `2048`

Comment: 2^1024 times as hard to break, which is a fairly large number. The CAs that I deal with won't accept 1024-bit keys any more.

Comment: Yep, the documentation for the RSAKeyGenerationParameters class is a _bit_ weak (pardon the pun), but the description of the constructor of the super, KeyGenerationParameters class sheds some light on it: `initialise the generator with a source of randomness **and a strength (in bits)**.` So in plain English: it specifies how long the keys will be.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Thanks for looking in to this. Length of the both keys are same. But I can see the difference in the keys.

Comment: @EJP So I'l forget about 1024 and use 2048 from now onwords. Is it OK ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Hmmmm, strange... [This question at security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37907/how-long-is-a-2048-bit-rsa-key) (though it is about a trivial math issue) makes me think that the key really should be twice as long... And by the way, how long are the keys in your case?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ EJP is right, the question today is 2048 or 4096... (even the [wiki has a quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Key_size_and_encryption_system) saying 1024 bit encryption is dead...)

Comment: @ppeterka66 Yes. Agreed. Soon I'l close this question. Understood now. This is just to seek clarification. i'm about to start generating a ceritifcate. Thanks for the valuable inputs. BTW, the length's are different, Just cross checked. Not exactly the double. `371,679`.

Comment: @EJP It's not 2^1024 times as hard to break. It's "only" a few billion times as hard. Unlike symmetric encryption, RSA's security doesn't scale like 2^n.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, When you say the lengths are not exactly double, what are you looking at?  At the file size?  An X509 certificate is made up of identity information, a public key, validity dates,  signature, etc....not just the key itself.  For RSA, the public key is made up of the modulus and an exponent.  The modulus is the value that is constrained by the key size.  You can see the actual modulus value along with the other values with the openssl command `openssl x509 -in my_cert.pem -text -noout`. Or if you only want to see the modulus, try `openssl x509 -in my_cert.pem -modulus -noout`.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of [`RSAKeyGenerationParameters`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/KeyGenerationParameters.html#KeyGenerationParameters%28java.security.SecureRandom,%20int%29) is

> `strength` - the size, in bits, of the keys we want to produce.

2048-bit RSA encryption is theoretically harder to break than 1024. But the number of bits in the public/private pair is typically defined by the system you're interacting with.

- [What does “128 / 256 bit SSL and 2048 bit CSR encryption” mean in practical terms?](https://serverfault.com/questions/313553/what-does-128-256-bit-ssl-and-2048-bit-csr-encryption-mean-in-practical-term)

Comment: Unlike the difference between 128 and 256 bit AES, the difference between RSA-1024 and RSA-2048 is not merely theoretical. RSA-1024 is withing the range of computational power affordable to larger attackers (e.g. the NSA).

Answer (score 2):

Asymmetric keys are typically easier to crack than symmetric keys of the same length. The longer the asymmetric key, the more computational power is required to determine the private key from the public key. Therefore, the longer the keys, the stronger the encryption.

Also, note that with RSA encryption, the plain text message cannot be longer than the key. So, if you are using a 1024 bit key, you can only encrypt a message body of up to 128 bytes (minus a few for overhead), or 256 bytes for a 2048 bit key.

So, the longer the asymmetric key, the longer the symmetric key or hash value can be passed inside.

It also takes longer (more computational power required) to generate longer key pairs, but unless you're dynamically creating key pairs, this isn't often an issue.

Comment: The size of the asymmetric key often does not matter for RSA encryption, as hybrid encryption is the norm. Same goes for the hash value really, even SHA-512 will easily fit into a signature generated by an RSA 1024 public key. So apart from the security, the size of the key should not matter too much.

Comment: @owlstead, Of course a SHA-512 hash value, which is 512 bits, will fit into a RSA 1024 bit cipher, but people do all kinds of interesting things with their asymmetric keys besides signing, and this limitation doesn't seem to be well known.